# How to loop through Angular mat-radio-buttons to delete values?

Tags: angular-material

I've already asked a bunch of experienced developers and they basically told me its impossible without using many if then else statements. Here's my hardcoded example that works but Im looking for something more efficient, something elegant. There are 10 questions, if I answer all of them but decide to go back and change question #5 for example, I want to delete all questions' answers after that question, doesnt matter which question you are on, basically if you go backwards on any question, delete everything after.In Angular, this is more difficult than you think. This is the hard coded of what currently works:

```
    clearAllQuestions() {
      if (this.q1 == 'N') {
       this.q2 = '';
       this.q3 = '';
       this.q4 = '';

     }
   else if (this.q2 == 'Y') {
   this.q3 = '';
   this.q4 = '';  

    }
  else if (this.q3 == 'Y') {
  this.q4 = '';
 
}
```

Is there anyway to identify which question you are currently on to erase everything after that? Initially I thought loop through and array but didnt work. Here is an example of how the questions are constructed in HTML. Please assume q2-q4 also have the same format.

```
       <div class="col-md-5">
      <mat-radio-group class="ans-radio-group"  [(ngModel)]="q1">
        <!--<mat-radio-button class="ans-radio-button" (change)="ClearAllQuestions()"
        *ngFor="let answer of answers" [value]="answer.key">-->{{ answer.value }}
        </mat-radio-button>
      </mat-radio-group>


    </div>
```

Comment: is it possible to have questions object with `q1, q2, q3`instead of q1, q2, q3 in class? or array?

Comment: Thats essentially what Im trying to achieve. I was hoping to get all the questions by way of document.getElementbyClass("ans-radio-button") but nothing returns. I think I might have to use formControl.